# Is there any way i get the reference of ChannelPipeline created when i a client connect to server on serverside?

Tags: tcp, netty, tcpserver

In case of synchronous TCP server when ever a client connects i get a reference of Client example :

```
 int serverPortNum = 9000;
socket while(true) {
     ServerSocket connectionSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPortNum);
     Socket dataSocket = connectionSocket.accept( );
     // pass this reference(dataSocket ) to other part of program to read or write depending on app logic
}
```

Now i want to use asynchronous TCP Server using Netty  so is there any way i can get the reference of ChannelPipeline or ChannelHandler created when a new client is connected.

On Client Side I can do it easily : sample code :
        NioClientSocketChannelFactory ncscf = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory( Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()); 
        ClientBootstrap clientBootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(ncscf);

```
    final DummyHandler  dummy = new DummyHandler();
    clientBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() { 
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception { 
            return Channels.pipeline(dummy); 
        } 
    }); 

    InetAddress inetaddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    ChannelFuturecf=clientBootstrap.connect(newInetSocketAddress(inetaddress,port));
```

So every time i create a new client i have new DummyHandler reference

On Server Side : sample Code :
     ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

```
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(new DummyServerHandler());
        }
    });


    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
   So when client request connection new DummyServerHandler object is created but i cannot get reference of this.
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the example servers such as echo server and HTTP snoop server?

Comment: @TrustinLee : I have checked EchoServer example but that i couldnt find where can i get reference . I have edited original question to explain my question in more details.

Answer (score 0):

I may missunderstood the question but wouldn't this work.

```
Channel.getpipeline()
```

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. When A new Client tries to connect with Server getPipeline method of ChannelPipelineFactory will be called . I want to get reference of each DummyServerHandler when a new client is connected.